# How to show active tab-pane inside tab-container on click event?

Tags: javascript

I am having menu links on one page & tab-container on another page. I want when someone click on one of the menu link it should go the page in which tab-container is there and show active tabpane of which menu has been clicked

Eg. Menu name: ab, ba, cd
    Tab name: ab, ba, cd

So I want when user click on menu 'ba' it should go to the page and showing the 'ba' as active tab and so on

Help me out using javascript

Answer (score 0):

It would be really helpful if you post sample of your code. If you want to identify which tab is clicked on another page, you probably need to pass menu name in query string as below.

```
<body>
<ul class="no-list">
    <li >
        <a href="page2.aspx?menu=ab" >ab</a>
    </li>
    <li >
        <a href="page2.aspx?menu=cd" >cd</a>
    </li>

</ul>
```

and call below javascript function on load of another page. You will get the value of clicked menu. now you need to write your logic to show active tabpane.

```
    function onloadcheck(){
    var queryString = location.search.substring(1); 
    alert(queryString.split('=')[1]);
};
```